# catch change event from input textbox that is being removed from the lost of focus event

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, cross-browser

I have a text type `<input>` and I'm listening to its on change events (so I can record the new new value elsewhere).  When a text `<input>` loses focus, it triggers a change event. This is good. I have another UI elements that when interacted, hide/destroy the container where that text `<input>` is contained. When that happens, a change event is triggered in Chromium but not in Firefox.

Here's a minimal example of my issue:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="reset_button">Reset Container</button>
    <button id="do_nothing_button">Do Nothing</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    function on_input_change(e) {
      console.log("on change", e.target.value);
    }

    function create_input_el() {
      const input_el = document.createElement("input");
      input_el.onchange = on_input_change;
      return input_el;
    }

    function reset_container() {
        const container = document.querySelector("#container");
        container.innerHTML = "";
        container.append(create_input_el());
    }
    reset_container();

    function on_reset_mouse_down(e) {
        console.log("on mouse down");
        reset_container();
    };
    const btn = document.querySelector("#reset_button");
    btn.onmousedown = on_reset_mouse_down;
  </script>
</html>
```

This will create a page with a text box and two buttons.  The text box logs to console change events. The reset button destroys the container and replaces it with a new text box.

If you enter something on the text box and then press the "Do Nothing" button, a change event is triggered (logged to the console). If you press the "Reset container" it first triggers a mouse down event (also logged to the console) and on Firefox that's the end of it while on chromium it still triggers the on change event.

Two questions from this:

1. how can I catch the change event on firefox / right approach to destroy the container / etc?
2. which one the *right* behaviour (and should I report this to chromium or firefox)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call the `blur()` method on the `input` elements before resetting the container. This will then trigger a `change` event if appropriate which will be handled before the container is destroyed with `container.innerHTML = ""`. Like so:

```
    function reset_container() {
      const container = document.querySelector("#container");
      const input_el = container.querySelector('input');
      if (document.activeElement === input_el)
        input_el.blur();
      container.innerHTML = "";
      container.append(create_input_el());
    }
```

Also, I'm not super clear on whether it is Firefox or Chrome that is right , but after searching their big trackers, I found an issue against Chromium about [firing `onscroll` events after the object lifetime](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1109552) so I'm leaning towards this being the same bug and a Chromium bug.